# How can we execute a string command and then get the result of it to assign a variable in shell script bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to  execute a string command and then get the result of it to assign a variable in shell script bash.
for example :

```
strCode="scontrol show jodid --dd $VALUE"
eval $strCode
```

The point here is this codepart worked but how can I get the results from the `

> eval

` command and assign it to a variable, because I need it to use.

when I type the `theResult=eval $strCode` it does not work.

thanks for the help

Comment: Storing commands in variables is generally a bad idea; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (and many previous questions here). Variables are for data, not executable code (and `eval` is a massive bug magnet). Storing *the result of running a command*, on the other hand, is a perfectly reasonable thing to use a variable for.

Comment: See _Command substitution_ in the bash man page.

Comment: problem SOLVED, thanks to all of you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```sh
strCode=$(scontrol show jodid --dd $VALUE)
echo "${strCode}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you are doing:

```
theResult=$(scontrol show jodid --dd $VALUE)
```

You should follow some bash tutorial, as this is a quite basic question.